Failed remediation script in Intune while "run script 64-bit PowerShell" option is turned on
I took the script for updating applications using Winget from this blog: https://scloud.work/winget-updates-proactive-remediations-2/
The blog says that scripts should be run in 64-bit powershell, but in my case the scripts do not run and throw out "failed" without explanation.
I already have several scripts that run in 32-bit and they work correctly.
I assume that the problem is not in the script itself, but in some configuration, maybe someone has encountered the same problem or knows in which direction to look?
Just to clarify, here is my script:
Detection script -
$app_2upgrade = "7zip.7zip"

$Winget = Get-ChildItem -Path (Join-Path -Path (Join-Path -Path $env:ProgramFiles -ChildPath "WindowsApps") -ChildPath "Microsoft.DesktopAppInstaller*_x64*\winget.exe")

if ($(&$winget upgrade) -like "* $app_2upgrade *") {
Write-Host "Upgrade available for: $app_2upgrade"
exit 1 # upgrade available, remediation needed
}
else {
Write-Host "No Upgrade available"
exit 0 # no upgraded, no action needed
}

Remediation script -
$app_2upgrade = "7zip.7zip"

try{
$Winget = Get-ChildItem -Path (Join-Path -Path (Join-Path -Path $env:ProgramFiles -ChildPath "WindowsApps") -ChildPath "Microsoft.DesktopAppInstaller*_x64*\winget.exe")

&$winget upgrade --exact $app_2upgrade --silent --force --accept-package-agreements --accept-source-agreements
exit 0

}catch{
Write-Error "Error while installing upgrade for: $app_2upgrade"
exit 1
}


Which script is failing - the detection script or the remediation script? And is "failed" a status description from the Intune management portal? No additional error messages or logs to be found nearby?

Remove --silent so you can get error messages and debug the problem.
